# How can I change the start page?

Tags: windows-phone-8

While developing my Windows Phone 8 application, I often want to launch straight into the page I'm working on. This is not always the Main Page. The article found [here](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/how-change-start-page-windows) talks about the App having an OnLaunched event handler. I think that is no longer (Maybe I'm just not seeing it). Is there a more current way of setting which page in the solution is launched first?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In App menifest change the start page to the page you want.

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer. Putting it here to save others who may run into this. It's in the manifest now. Go Project > Properties > WMAppManifest.xml. In the editor change Application UI > Navigation Page to the page you need.

Answer (score 3):

in windows universal apps:

Shared->App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    /*...*/
        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
          /*...*/

            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
        }
     /*...*/
}
```

change MainPage to the name of your own Page

Answer (score 1):

You can also change it in App.xaml in the `Application_Launching` event
by using something like:

```
App.RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Startup.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
```

Keep in mind, you have to change 'Startup.xaml' to your own xaml file.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Phone apps written in C#:

1. Open the WMAppManifest.xml file.
2. Under the Application UI tab, change the value for Navigation Page from the default MainPage.xaml to YourPageName.xaml (replace YourPageName with the name of the xaml file you want to use).